# Running `bundle exec sidekiq` throws Celluloid::DeadTaskError: cannot resume a dead task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I followed Sidekiq's easy setup instructions found [here](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/), but I could not get it to work.

Here's the stack trace. I have also started the redis server. Anyone know what I am missing here?

```
E, [2012-09-28T09:11:36.468019 #71427] ERROR -- : Celluloid::SupervisionGroup crashed!
Celluloid::DeadTaskError: cannot resume a dead task
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:47:in `rescue in resume'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:44:in `resume'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/responses.rb:11:in `dispatch'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `handle_message'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:195:in `run'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:184:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/thread_handle.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in `block in create'
I, [2012-09-28T09:11:36.468316 #71427]  INFO -- : Terminating 2 actors...
I, [2012-09-28T09:11:36.468955 #71427]  INFO -- : Shutdown completed cleanly
/Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:35:in `yield': uninitialized fiber (FiberError)
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:35:in `suspend'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/task.rb:19:in `suspend'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:70:in `call'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/proxies/actor_proxy.rb:19:in `_send_'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid.rb:90:in `new_link'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:133:in `start'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:120:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:80:in `new'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:80:in `add'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:71:in `supervise_as'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervisor.rb:17:in `block in supervise_as'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/supervision_group.rb:63:in `initialize'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:57:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:320:in `block in handle_message'
    from /Users/ernsheong/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/celluloid-0.12.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:22:in `block in initialize'
```

Comment: Hey Jonathan, did you manage to get this fixed?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi David, I couldn't get it to work in localhost on my Macbook, but it works in the remote server for some reason *shrugs*

Comment: did you you install redis? if not: brew install redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this again.
Had the same error when trying out the falcon patch for ruby 1.9.3, resolved it by switching from 1.9.3-p0-falcon to ruby 1.9.3-p327.